# Perguntas referente a "programação de servidores"

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Minha dúvida é referente a "programação de servidores" [Número de processadores no Hyper-V](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57863/numero-de-processadores-no-hyper-v)

Li na central de ajuda [pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) que o foco é "programação" acho que a minha dúvida é sim enquadrada como "programação de servidores" o SO inglês abrange configurações de servidores tipo [Zabbix JMX Tomcat monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862967/zabbix-jmx-tomcat-monitoring).

Seria bom se tivéssemos um conteúdo desses em Português, porque a área onde atua um profissional de programação geralmente atua um profissional que gerência os servidores dos programadores, e acredite, este profissional também tem dúvidas e também precisa de ajuda.

Comment: De acordo com esse tópico o assunto "Desenvolvimento de scripts para servidores" faz parte do escopo do nosso site: [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/3117). Isso é apenas um adendo, não estou dizendo que a pergunta em questão é sobre isso ou não.

Comment: caso minha pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57863/numero-de-processadores-no-hyper-v seja mesmo fora do escopo, sugiro que o primeiro ponto do help/on-topic seja alterado "um problema específico de programação" para "um problema específico de linguagem de programação"

Comment: minhas dúvidas referente a zabbix, vou ter que ficar preso ao SO inglês, se o pessoal abrisse uma tag zabbix, eu poderia ajudar quem esta começando a usar essa ferramenta, acho que no stack overflow poderíamos incorporar todas as dúvidas do setor/departamento de TI todos estes programadores não somente os programadores de código fonte.

Comment: Sem opinar sobre a pergunta estar ou não no escopo do site, você está confundindo "configuração" com "programação".

Comment: @bfavaretto estou me referindo ao termo programação na sua plenitude do termo/definição não no jargão da informatica.

Programação é derivação fem. sing. de programar

1. .Ato ou efeito de programar; plano; programa; conjunto de programas ou planos.

2. Estabelecer um plano para fazer algo. = PLANEAR, PLANIFICAR

3. Fornecer instruções a uma máquina para um procedimento automático (ex.: programar a máquina de lavar; programar o alarme).

4. Submeter a uma rotina ou aprendizagem para reagir de determinada maneira. Mas claro que foi só uma forma de esbravejar meu descontentamento.

Comment: Perguntas sobre como programar máquinas de lavar, alarmes, ou videocassetes, essas sim eu tenho certeza de que são off-topic :)

Comment: @bfavaretto depende, se for programar à nível de usuário é off, se for programar no desenvolvimento do produto é on :)

Comment: Independente das brincadeiras (e concordo com o @Math acima), você fez bem em levantar a discussão. É assim que se consolida o que a comunidade aceita e o que não aceita. Vamos ver no que dá.

Comment: @Math então como é "maq. servidor" creio que não seja esse nível de usuário. Acho que algum moderador já poderia dar alguma orientação/explicação

Comment: @MaisonSakamoto na verdade eu tava pegando no pé do bfavaretto, rs.. Falando sério agora, existem alguns critérios que torna sua pergunta on topic no site, pode ser que a comunidade tenha entendido errado e fecharam sua pergunta mesmo que haja embasamento para mantê-la aberta, por isso que o debate no Meta é importante. Eu não dei minha opinião pois não formei uma opinião sobre ele, gostaria que alguém com mais embasamento falasse primeiro. Sobre você ainda não ter tido pessoas debatendo o assunto com você, acalme-se que em breve alguém participa (ou não, mas acredito que sim).

Comment: Sobre a parte que cita da moderação, saiba que [**o StackOverflow é moderado por todos nós**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), portanto qualquer um pode expor a opinião aqui para fomentar o debate, isso pode acontecer logo ou pode demorar um pouco mais, não necessariamente precisamos da figura do moderador que possui o diamante (♦) dando parecer sobre tudo no site.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de editar a pergunta. Não fiz mais nada porque não faço a menor ideia se é off ou on-topic.

Comment: Bom dia, peço novamente que analisem essa questão já pensando nela como um "grupo" pois ser for aceita será bem vinda outras perguntas nesse sentido como o caso do zabbix/nagios que citei, será um divisor de barreiras, creio que seja uma questão nesse sentido Aceitaremos profissionais do tipo "analista de redes/servidores/infra" aqui no StackOverflow ou estes terão que procurar outra casa para tirar suas dúvidas e trocarem experiências.

Comment: concordo que certos casos poderiam ser permitidos, porém depende da interpretação de quem está observando o caso. Como exemplo, se analisarmos bem, teríamos que banir as questões sobre htaccess, muito comum entre os usuários php pois lidam com apache em sua maioria.